# How to parametrize the curve of intersection of a hemisphere and a cylinder

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I am given this question:

> Denote by $C$ the curve of intersection of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 2x$ and the upper hemisphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4, z ≥ 0$ with counterclockwise orientation as viewed from the above of the $xy$-plane. Compute the line integral $\int_{C} F·d\vec{r}$ if $F(x,y,z)=(y,z,x)$.

My approach:

> Apply spherical coordinates. Put $x = 2\sin\phi\cos\theta$, $y = 2\sin\phi\sin\theta$ and $z = 2\cos\phi$ (#).
> Plug into the cylinder, we would have $4\sin^2\phi\cos^2\theta + 4\sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta = 4\sin\phi\cos\theta$, which implies $\sin\phi = \cos\theta$ , or in other words, $\cos\phi = \sin\theta$.
> Put it back to (#), we would have $x = 2\cos^2\theta$, $y = 2\cos\theta\sin\theta$ and $z = 2\sin\theta$.
> Hence a parametrization of C is given by $r(\theta) = (2\cos^2\theta, 2\cos\theta\sin\theta, 2\sin\theta)$, where $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.
> Then we can compute the line integral using the parametrization.

May I know if this parametrization is fine and is there any better method? Thanks.

Comment: The parametrization is OK, except that it goes below the xy plane. To get the upper hemisphere only, use $0\le\theta\le \pi$

Comment: Thank you very much!